# Weird space character can't be matched

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I'm stuck with this here, can someone help me solve this mystery ?

```
var t1 = "an excellence award can";
var t2 = "an excellence award can";
var r1 = t1.match('excellence award', 'gi'); 
var r2 = t2.match('excellence award', 'gi');
console.log(r1); // null (can't find it)
console.log(r2); // [...] (find it)
```

From what I observed, `t1` has a weird space character between 'excellence' and 'award', which prevents regex to match the word `excellence award`. I duplicated `t1` and made `t2`, then I simply deleted that space and put it back again manually, then it matched.

It is obvious that there is something wrong with that space, but couldn't figure it out what. Here is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/uw8m6far/

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a regular no-breaking space, `\xA0`. Use `\s` to match it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string contains a non-breaking space, you can easily find it in [this Unicode converter](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/).

Use an `\s` shorthand character class to match any whitespace, including a non-breaking space `\u00A0`:

```js
var t1 = "an excellence award can"; // Here, \u00A0 is between e and a
var t2 = "an excellence award can"; // Here is a regular ASCII space
var rx = /excellence\saward/gi;
var r1 = t1.match(rx); 
var r2 = t2.match(rx);
console.log(r1); 
console.log(r2);
```

See [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> `\s` - Matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form feed, line feed. Equivalent to `[ \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]`.

Comment: That was it. Updated the fiddle. I'll accept this in 6 mins. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code in a hex editor. In the first string, you have a non-breakable space (`0xa0`) instead of a normal space (`0x20`).

Use `\s` instead of a literal space in your regex to avoid this problem (unless you need to discriminate between spaces, tabs and newlines).